# How to assert MustHaveHappend(Collection.That.Contains(object)) in fake it easy

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, repository-pattern, fakeiteasy

I have a course repository as follows in the Arrange

```
A.CallTo(
            () => _courseClientStatusRepository.GetTnCoursesForClientStatus()).Returns(new List<CourseClientStatusCreationDto>
                {
                    new CourseClientStatusCreationDto { CourseTnId = Enums.CourseLevel.Beginner  },
                    new CourseClientStatusCreationDto { CourseTnId = Enums.CourseLevel.Intermediate, },
                    new CourseClientStatusCreationDto { CourseTnId = Enums.CourseLevel.Advanced,  }
                }
            );
```

In the Act I have a method that calls the

```
void CreateClientCourseStatus(List<CourseClientStatusDto> courseClientStatusDto);
```

method of the `ICourseClientStatusRepository`

and in the Assert, I have the following. The first assert passes, the second and third asserts fail.

```
A.CallTo(
            () => _courseClientStatusRepository.CreateClientCourseStatus(A<List<CourseClientStatusDto>>.Ignored))
            .MustHaveHappened();

        A.CallTo(
            () => _courseClientStatusRepository.CreateClientCourseStatus(A<List<CourseClientStatusDto>>.That.Contains(A<CourseClientStatusDto>.Ignored)))
            .MustHaveHappened();


        A.CallTo(
            () => _courseClientStatusRepository.CreateClientCourseStatus(A<List<CourseClientStatusDto>>.That.Contains(A<CourseClientStatusDto>.That.Matches(
                x => x.CourseTnId == Enums.CourseLevel.Beginner               
                ))))
                .MustHaveHappened();
```

I am at least expecting the second assert to pass at it's expecting an instance of an object of type CourseClientStatusDto , where its specific values are not important, hence i used the .Ignored property.

Is there perhaps something that i'm doing wrong to assert if a collection contains a specific object (using fake it easy .mustHaveHappened() method) ?

Answer (score 1):

@Ntu, can I ask what version of FakeItEasy you're using?

The `A<T>.Ignored` property is only applicable when used as a parameter specifier during call configuration or verification; it can't be used elsewhere, for example in the `Contains` method. As of FakeItEasy 4.1.1, you should get a clear error indicating this. For example, with FakeItEasy 4.3.0, I see this when I run an approximation of your test:

`Test 'FakeItEasyQuestions2015.Ntu.NestedConstraint' failed: System.InvalidOperationException : An argument constraint, such as That, Ignored, or _, cannot be nested in an argument.`

We frequently update the package, so it's always a good idea to upgrade for bug fixes and improvements.

You can replace your last two checks with something like this:

```
 A.CallTo(() => _courseClientStatusRepository.CreateClientCourseStatus(A<List<CourseClientStatusDto>>.That.Not.IsEmpty()))
    .MustHaveHappened();

A.CallTo(() => _courseClientStatusRepository.CreateClientCourseStatus(
A<List<CourseClientStatusDto>>.That.Matches(l => l.Exists(i => i.CourseTnId == Enums.CourseLevel.Beginner))))
    .MustHaveHappened();
```

While I'm commenting, I can't help but notice that in your Arrange, the return value of the `A.CallTo` is not used, so you won't be specifying any actual behaviour (unless you just left that out for brevity…). Consider adding the [FakeItEasy.Analyzer.CSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FakeItEasy.Analyzer.CSharp/) to your project; it'll warn you of such problems!

Comment: @ Blair, the last two checks are now working, your code helped, thanks. I'm using version 3.4.0 of Fake It Easy. And yes, I wanted to summarize the code in the Arrange. I definitely will be adding FakeItEasy.Analyzer.CSharp